# Proof of this Complex Hahn-Banach theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Case:

[image]

which reminds me of some version of the Hahn-Banach theorem. 
So I think we need to prove the sublinearity i.e. positive homogeneity and the subadditivity.

### My Proposal #2 based on Svetoslav's suggestion

Corollary 3.1.7/p.48 from the book "Functional analysis (An introduction)" by Yuli Eidelman, Vitali Milman, Antonis Tsolomitis - converted to this case:

Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. Let $v \in X \setminus Z$ and $Z \subset X$ is a closed subspace of a normed space $X$, meaning the distance 
\begin{equation*}
d = dist(v, Z) > 0. 
\end{equation*}
Then, there exists $\Phi \in X'$ such that $\Phi(v) \neq 0$ and  $\Phi(u)=0$ for all $u \in Z$ ( meaning $\Phi(Z)=0$ or $Z\subset Ker (\Phi)$ ).

**Proof**: First consider $Z_{\Phi} = span(v, Z)$: 
\begin{equation*}
Z_{\Phi} = \{ \lambda v + u: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, u \in Z \}.
\end{equation*}
Let 
\begin{equation*}
\Phi(z) := \lambda. 
\end{equation*}
where the function $\Phi(z)$ is **well defined** because $z = \lambda v + u$ can be written in a unique way: $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u \in Z$ are defined uniquely by $z$:
 Indeed, if $z=\lambda_1v+u_1=\lambda_2v+u_2$, where $u_1, u_2\in Z$, then
$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)v + 1\cdot (u_1-u_2)=0$. Now, if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2\Rightarrow u_1=u_2$. If $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2\Rightarrow v=-\frac{u_1-u_2}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\in Z$ which is a contradiction with that $v\notin Z$

**The linearity of this function**: let $\mu\in\mathbb K$ $z_1,z_2,z\in  Z_{\Phi}$ where $z_1=\lambda_1 v+ u_1$, $z_2=\lambda_2 v+u_2$, $z=\lambda v+u$, $u_1,u_2,u\in Z$. 
1)
$$\Phi(z_1+z_2) =\Phi(\lambda_1 v+u_1 +\lambda_2 v+ u_2)=\Phi((\lambda_1+\lambda_2)v +(u_1+u_2))$$ which by the definition of $\Phi$ equals $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=\Phi(z_1)+\Phi(z_2)$.

2)
$$\Phi(\mu z)=\Phi(\mu(\lambda v+u))=\Phi(\mu\lambda v+\mu u)=\mu\lambda$$
because $\mu u\in Z$

Now, it is clear that $\Phi(u)=\Phi(0\cdot v+u)=0,\,\,\forall u\in Z$, so $\Phi(Z)=0$. Also $\Phi(v)=\Phi(1\cdot v + 0)=1\neq 0$. By Hahn Banach theorem we can extend the linear bounded functional $\Phi$ defined on the linear subspace $Z_{\Phi}$ to a linear and bounded functional $\bar \Phi$ with the same norm on the whole space $X$.

How can you prove rigorously the Complex Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: your space $X$ is normed ?

Comment: So i think if you take the quotient space $X/E$ so it will be normed too and as $v\not\in E$ you can find a bounded functional $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(v)=\|v\|\neq 0$ but we know that $(X/E)^*\simeq E^°$. so i think this solve your problem.

Comment: For the proof of this Corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem, see Corollary 3.1.7/p.48 from the book "Functional analysis (An introduction)" by Yuli Eidelman, Vitali Milman, Antonis Tsolomitis

Comment: In your case $v\in X\setminus Z$ and $Z\subset X$ is a closed subspace means that  the distance $d=dist(v,Z)>0$. $\Phi (u)=0,\forall u\in Z$ means $\Phi (Z)=0$. Therefore in Eidelman's book it is proved a bit more than what you need in your exercise. Namely it is proved that you can find $\Phi$ such that  $0\neq\Phi(v)=d=dist(v,Z)$ and such that $\|\Phi\|=1$

Comment: @Svetoslav I added my proposal based on the book, the hint and your comment. How would you the situation change if `z = \lambda v - u`. Why is there the minus sign in the hint?

Comment: I edited your question. The proposed space $\left\{ \lambda v-u\right\}$ is the same as $\left\{ \lambda v+u\right\}$ where $u\in Z$, because $Z$ is a linear subspace, so if $u\in Z$ then $-u\in Z$. Also I erased the additional things about the norm of the functional and that $\Phi(v)=d$. This is just some particulars, that come out if you define the functional $\Phi(z)=\lambda\cdot d$ instead of just $\lambda$, as it is in your Hint.